# oscillation in Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER data

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am searching for an explanation why the TYPE_ACCELEROMETER data is oscillating. My Moto G 360 2nd gen gives me this output when resting on a flat table (z Coord. values)

[image]

I know that the TYPE_GRAVITY gives me much better results (even line on ~9,81). But what is the reason that TYPE_ACCELEROMETER data are oscillating? Are those data "raw" and " unflitered" sensordata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre right, TYPE_ACCELEROMETER gives you raw and unformatted data. including assembly inaccuracies and every litte oscillation. TYPE_GRAVITY is normend on "normal" g